# listbox not updating content when data source changes

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm working on a somewhat large WP7 project, and my current task is to implement offline functionality.

I've got a listbox which should only display items when the device is connected to the internet, and display an empty view otherwise.

I've got an event handler wired up which fires when connectivity changes, where I retrieve the neccesary data for the listbox if I've got a connection.

The problem is that when I run the app in offline mode, and then turn the Wi-fi on, the data for the listbox updates but not the UI itself

Here is the XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="lstItemCategories" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCategories, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemCategory, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,-15,0,60" Tap="lstItemCategories_Tap">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="78" Width="432">
                                <Image Height="70" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="image1" Stretch="Uniform"  Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
                                <ListBoxItem toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Foreground="{StaticResource darkGrey}"/>
                                </ListBoxItem>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

In the ViewModel I've got an ObservableCollection for the Binding:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ItemCategory> ItemCategories
    {
        get { return itemCategories; }
        set
        {
            itemCategories = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemCategories");
        }
    }
```

And I've got a backgroundworker which retrieves the items I need once the device is connected to the internet, and the RunWorkerCompleted method:

```
void itemCategoryWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    App.ItemCategories = (List<ItemCategory>)e.Result;

    ItemCategories = new ObservableCollection<ItemCategory>(App.ItemCategories);
}
```

So the ItemCategories property which is wired to the UI is updated, but not the UI itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. the change to the ItemCategories must be invoked on the UI thread:

```
((MainView)view).Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    ItemCategories = new ObservableCollection<ItemCategory>(App.ItemCategories);
                });
```